# codeigniter load ajax request with controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, frameworks

I've seen some tutorials regarding CodeIgniter and Ajax, but I wonder.

I have a page that has about 30-40 different views, with associated controllers and models.
I had thought about doing that parts of this page is downloaded via ajax, but if I download view via ajax, it will not belong to or connect to the controller.
(For example if I have a function in a controller which is connected to a model, etc.)

So my question is as follows, it is possible for me to simply redo my website structure so I somehow can use Ajax to download portions of my page, and that it is connected to the controller and model as needed to take off submit forms, etc.?

Comment: You want a page to load and pull views from different controller actions?

Comment: @bankzilla I want a page to load and if i do submit within that page, it will work with the controller and model that belongs to that page, because i have 1 controller and model for each of my pages.

Comment: Assuming you're wanting to submit to the same page, why not just have the form action the same as the current page? If not and you want say the edit page to post to the posts/update controller with ajax, build a form as you would normally, with the action pointing to the page where you want the data posted, then just send it with ajax and use the form action as the url to post to.